# If $(b-a) = (ba^2 - ab^2)$, show that $a=b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am slightly stuck on this seemlingly simple problem that I encoutered as part of a problem to show that the orthogonality condition of $M_{2\times2}$ matrices given by $\sum_i a_{ij}a_{jk} = \delta_{jk}$, where the $a_{ij}$ are the matrix entries, implies that $\det(M) = \pm 1$.

If $b(1-a^2) = a(1-b^2)$, show that $a=b$ or $a=1, b=-1$ or $a=-1, b =1$ is the only solutions where $a,b \in \mathbb R$ or give a counter-example if the statement is false.

I am thinking of testing the intervals $a,b \in (-\infty,-1); a,b \in (1,\infty)$ and $a,b \in [-1,1]$ seperately and showing in each case that if $a > b$ or $b > a$ then equality cannot hold. However, this requires testing lots of cases and I thought there might be a simpler way.

A hint will help a lot.

Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** By rearranging and factoring, notice that:
\begin{align*}
(ba^2 - ab^2) - (b - a) &= 0 \\
ab(a - b) + (a - b) &= 0 \\
(ab + 1)(a - b) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Whao! That was fast.

Comment: $(a,b)=(k,-1/k)$ is also a solution

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking your equation has also the solution $a=-1/b$ with $a,b \neq 0$...